# setting up my cgi script on mod_wsgi

Tags: python, cgi, mod-wsgi

I have a basic cgi script that I would to be called from mod_wsgi. I have already set up a basic hello world example on mod_wsgi. How do I set my cgi script on mod_wsgi?

I understand that there's an application entrance point called "application", but how do I get my script to run from here?

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

My cgi-script contains lots of imports, loose code, definitions, and print statements.

Comment: Why not just have the web server handle the script? It already knows how to talk CGI.

Comment: Are you implying that (with the apache config set up correctly) I can run my cgi file (now a .wsgi) as is? I thought there needs to be a "def application" entrance point for all wsgi applications.

Comment: CGI applications are not WSGI applications.

Comment: Some logic should remain the same though. Is there a lot of rewrite with converting a cgi application to wsgi?

Comment: There can be; it depends on how complex the script is and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial contains a CGI-to-WSGI bridge module, found here:

http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/tip/mercurial/hgweb/wsgicgi.py